# Laravel: Get pivot data for specific many to many relation

Tags: laravel, relationship

My `User` model has many `Target` and vice versa.
Now I've got a given `User` and given `Target` and I want to access pivot data from their relation. The pivot column is called `type`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

On the relationships for both `User` and `Target`, tack on a `->withPivot('type')` which will instruct Laravel to include that column. Then once you have your result set, you can access the field with `$user->pivot->type`.

If you're not iterating over a collection, but have a user and one of their targets and want the `type` field, you could use `$target = $user->targets->find($targetId)` and access the type with `$target->pivot->type`.

More at http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables

Comment: Thanks, I didn't remember to use find!

Comment: this answer is not relevant with laravel 8.

Comment: @Bapi can you please provide the reason, why is not relevant?

Answer (score 4):

## Laravel 8.x

After accessing the relationship, you can access the intermediate table using the pivot attribute on your models

```
foreach ($user->targets as $target) {
    echo $target->pivot->created_at;
}
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns

Answer (score 0):

You can also limit columns by passing array as 2nd arg to simplePaginate

```
$query->users()->simplePaginate($per_page, ['users.id', 'users.email']);
```