# How to get data from Pivot table?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I tried to get data from pivot table as:

```
@foreach ($announcements as $index => $item)
      {{dd($item->pivot->category->translate('en')->name)}}
      {{dd($item->pivot->category->name)}}
@endforeach
```

I attached screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Does this one help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27434338/laravel-get-pivot-data-for-specific-many-to-many-relation

Comment: and what happened?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldnot mention the model name:

```
{{dd($item->pivot->name)}}
```

if `items` and `categories` has a pivot table `item_category` with attribute `name` then, `{{dd($item->pivot->name)}}` gives the value of name attribute