# How to get pivot data in many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I created the customer_products table to store the different_price data. Now I trying to return the different_price to show the data. How do I get the data from the customer_products table?

```
//Product table
    public function customers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Customer', 'customer_products')->withPivot('different_price');
    }

    //Customer table
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Product', 'customer_products')->withPivot('different_price');
    }
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27434338/laravel-get-pivot-data-for-specific-many-to-many-relation