# How to count the total price of order?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have these tables:

```
Orders: 
id - status -user_id - address_id 
1     await    1          1 

products:
id -  name -   price  - quantity
1     test1    100$       5 
2     test2    50$        5 


order_product:
order_id - product_id - quantity
 1           1            2
 1           2            2

cities:
id - name - shipping_charges
1    NY       30$
```

How can I count the total price of the these columns:

for each product:

```
  products(price) * order_product(quantity)
```

for all products with shipping_charges

```
- products(price) * order_product(quantity) + cities(shipping_charges)
```

Comment: `address_id` connect to cities?

Comment: @TsaiKoga yeah it's

Comment: so if one product[$20] has two orders, [qty: 1, qty: 2,] two order has same cities' `shipping_charges`[$1, $1]. So you want to cal one product's shipping_charges is `20*(1+2) + 1` or `20*(1+2) + 2*1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the *pivot* table columns by accessing the `pivot` attribute, this has been there for a [long while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27434338/laravel-get-pivot-data-for-specific-many-to-many-relation).

> By default, only the model keys will be present on the pivot object. If your pivot table contains extra attributes, you must specify them when defining the relationship:

In your case you can define the relationship like in the following code:

```php
class Order extends Model {
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class)->withPivot('quantity')
    }
}
```

Now the `quantity` column on the `order_product` table will be accessible via the `pivot` attribute (e.g. `$order->products()->first()->pivot->quantity`).

In the end, here is the resulting code to calculate the order total:

```php
$total = 0;
foreach ($product as $products) {
    $total += $product->price * $product->pivot->quantity
}

$total += $order->address()->city->shipping_charges
```

> Source: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 1):

Find the sum of a field by using laravel collection  by doing something like this;

$profuctTotal=Product::all()->sum('price'); 
Do same for others using Eloquent models.

Comment: the problem with the pivot table there is model for it how can I handle it!

Comment: Now I have this ( $order->products->sum('price') it's ok but how can I * this with the pivot table that I have

Answer (score 1):

- If you don't use any model then use this raw query

$orderitem = DB::table('order_product')->where('order_id', 'your order id')->get();

```
    // Now create a foreach loop for get total price 

    $total = 0;

    foreach($orderitem as $order){
        $porduct = DB::table('products')->where('id', $order->product_id)->first();
        $total += $porduct->price * $order->quantity;
    }
    // now you got sub total
    $shipping = DB::table('cities')->where('id', 'Orders table address column')->first();
    $subtotal = $tatal + $shipping->shipping_charges;
```