# Foreach each product then get total price?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this two tables:

```
    Orders: 
    id - status -user_id - address_id 
    1     await    1          1 

    products:
    id -  name -   price  - quantity
    1     test1    100$       5 
    2     test2    50$        5 


    order_product:
    order_id - product_id - quantity
    1           1            2
    1           2            2
```

Relation in Order Model:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Product')->withPivot('quantity')->withTimestamps();
}
```

I need this:

foreach each product then MULTIPLY the price of each product with the third table in `order_product(quantity)`??

My Shut:

```
 foreach ($order->products as $product) {

        $total_price = $product->pivot->quantity * $product->price;

  }
```

I need after this to sum the total price after MULTIPLY with pivot(quantity) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count the total price of order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60011582/how-to-count-the-total-price-of-order)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The orders and products' relationship are many-to-many.

#### Join:

You can use left join:

```php
$product_query = Product::leftjoin('order_product', 'order_product.product_id', '=','product.id')
       ->select("product.*", DB::raw("SUM(product.price * order_product.quantity) AS total_price"));
```

So you can get the product with total_price:

```php
$product_query->find(1)->total_price;
```

#### Accessor:

You can use accessor to get the attributes,

In your Product model, use `withPivot` to add pivot's data, and use accessor:

```php
    protected $appends = ["total_price"];

    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class, 'order_product', 'product_id', 'order_id')
                   ->withPivot('quantity') // You need to add the pivot datas here.
                  ->withTimestamps();
    }

    // Add accessor here:
    public function getTotalPriceAttribute() {
        return $this->price * $this->orders->sum('pivot.quantity');
    }
```

So you can get the product with total_price:

```php
Product::first()->total_price;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
foreach ($order->products as $product) {

        $total_price += $product->pivot->quantity * $product->price;

  }
```

just add += so that after multiplication it will get added to total.

Answer (score 0):

try this

in your model

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class, 'order_product', 'product_id', 'order_id')
               ->withPivot('quantity')
               ->withTimestamps();
}
```

and  change

```
$total_price = 0;

foreach ($order->products as $product) {

        $total_price += $product->pivot->quantity * $product->price;

  }
```